# .htaccess - URL rewrite help

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have this code in my .htacess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/(\d.*) article.php?id=$1
```

When I open a link like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/article/10
```

The page will open but no images, CSS, JS file loaded, I guess the problem is that pages are going to this URL `article/10`, so every URL in the `article.php` is changing to new URL even after redirect works.

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on where your resources are stored and how they are linked in your article, your article will need to point to something like http://localhost/mysite/image to reference an image without it being redirected by your script

Comment: when I call the page article.php - the page will open successfully without any problems but when I am using URL rewrite, I face this problem, so the problem is in .htaccess file, right?

Comment: you have a `/` after `article` so article.php does not match the rewrite rule and does not redirect

Comment: what should I do make this idea work, I want to have URL like this one `http://localhost/mysite/article/10` - how I can make it work?

Comment: The method you have should work, as you have shared resources such as images and javascript documents you should have them in a shared folder such as `localhost/mysite/images` and reference them in your article that way such as `<image src="/mysite/images/image1.jpg" />`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid putting this `/mysite` in every link on the page or is there any trick?

Comment: if you set up the server to configure /mysite/ as the root directory then yes if your on Apache then its the htdocs in combination with the server root in /etc/conf